# Merging two different lists of datetime intervals

Tags: python, algorithm, datetime, intervals

I'm trying to merge two lists. Each list has a start date, end date and a value. Resulting list must have both values. Intervals from list 2 will need to be split when intervals don't match. I'm able to this going day by day and obtaining values from both lists. However, this is extremely inefficient, so it won't work with big lists. I would like to know what is the most efficient way of doing this

Here's an example:

LIST 1

```
[
  ['ALL', 'ALL', 2],
  ['2013-11-24', '2013-11-30', 4],
  ['2013-12-24', '2014-01-01', 3],  
]
```

LIST 2

```
[
    ['2013-07-08', '2013-08-29', '1800.00'],
    ['2013-08-30', '2013-09-06', '1800.00'],    
    ['2013-10-01', '2013-10-31', '1500.00'],
    ['2013-11-24', '2013-12-03', '400.00'],
    ['2013-12-24', '2014-01-03', '500.00'], 
]
```

RESULTING LIST

```
[   
    ['2013-07-08', '2013-08-29', '1800.00', 2],
    ['2013-08-30', '2013-09-06', '1800.00', 2], 
    ['2013-10-01', '2013-10-31', '1500.00', 2], 

    ['2013-11-24', '2013-11-30', '400.00', 4],
    ['2013-12-01', '2013-12-03', '400.00', 2],

    ['2013-12-24', '2014-01-01', '500.00', 3],  
    ['2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '500.00', 2]   
]
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Are the lists sorted when you get them?

Comment: Yes. Sorted by start date.

Comment: Create a loop that looks at the next element from each list.  If they are the same, merge and go on to the next element in both lists.  Otherwise, if they overlap, deal with that.  Otherwise, deal with the earlier element and then go to the next element in that list, but stay on the same element in the other list.